# Can't get output voltage out of LT1011 (LTSpice)

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, comparator

How come I can't get any voltage out of this op amp ? (I have to use that one, can't change it)

[image]

THe green signal is the input, the blue one is the output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This device does not pull its output high.  You must connect a resistor to a positive voltage to the output pin if you want it go high.    This is considered a “feature” for comparators.

Some other devices do have an output that goes high without a resistor.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt1011.pdf) (emphasis added):

> Output Transistor The LT1011 output transistor is truly floating in
> the sense that **no current flows into or out of either the collector or
> emitter when the transistor is in the “off” state**. The equivalent
> circuit is shown in Figure 5.

To get an output that goes from near ground to some other (positive) voltage (assuming emitter is grounded) you need a pullup resistor. This allows a comparator with (say) +/- 15V supplies to be used with 3.3V or 5V logic.

[image]

For example, here is a pair used as a "window comparator" with 3.3V output. The output is only high when the input is within the range of +5 to -5V.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The opamp is a comparator, If you want a sine wave output, you need to use an op amp.

If you did have an op amp, you need negative feedback (though the negative terminal)